# Adding ModelState.IsValid breaks my page in c# MVC

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am working on a db that allows a user to add courses, then add books to those courses, while having a many to many relationship with students. I got a page set up that shows a selected course, a list of its books, and a few of its student.

I managed to get the ability to add books on that same page, however, whenever I add a ModelState.IsValid check, it completely breaks when I press the submit button. I've tried googling and different methods but I seem to not be able to get around this... I'm probably missing something obvious, but I don't know what it is...

Here is my course DB object

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SchoolPracticeDB.Entities
{
    public class Course
    {

        public int CourseId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a course name.")]
        public string? CourseName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter credits worth.")]
        public int? Credits { get; set; }

        //nav to students
        public ICollection<Enrollment>? Enrollments { get; set; }

        //nav to all of its books (zero to many)
        public ICollection<Book>? Books { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is my CourseDetailsViewModel

```
using SchoolPracticeDB.Entities;

namespace SchoolPracticeDB.Models
{
    public class CourseDetailsViewModel
    {

        public Course? ActiveCourse { get; set; }

        public Book? NewBook { get; set; }

        public double? AverageMark { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is my controller method that works without the check:

```
[HttpPost("/courses/{id}/books")]
public IActionResult AddBookToCourseById(int id, CourseDetailsViewModel courseDetailsViewModel)
{

    var course = _courseDbContext.Courses
        .Include(c => c.Books)
        .Include(c => c.Enrollments)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.Student).Where(c => c.CourseId == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    course.Books.Add(courseDetailsViewModel.NewBook);
    _courseDbContext.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("GetCourseById", "Course", new { id = id });

}
```

But when I add any check it crashes and gives me null errors
Here's the code with the check

```
[HttpPost("/courses/{id}/books")]
public IActionResult AddBookToCourseById(int id, CourseDetailsViewModel courseDetailsViewModel)
{
          
    var course = _courseDbContext.Courses
        .Include(c => c.Books)
        .Include(c => c.Enrollments).ThenInclude(e => e.Student)
        .Where(c => c.CourseId == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        course.Books.Add(courseDetailsViewModel.NewBook);
        _courseDbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("GetCourseById", "Course", new { id = id });
    }
    else
    {

        courseDetailsViewModel.ActiveCourse = _courseDbContext.Courses
                .Include(c => c.Books)
                .Include(c => c.Enrollments).ThenInclude(e => e.Student)
                .Where(c => c.CourseId == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        courseDetailsViewModel.NewBook.Course = courseDetailsViewModel.ActiveCourse;

        return View("CourseDetails", courseDetailsViewModel);
    }

}
```

And here's the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vgA4.png)

The only way I have been able to get it to work is by adding hidden inputs for the course's required values in the form itself: in this case id (which seems normal) and then CourseName and Credits (which doesn't seem right), since I'm trying to add a book not a course as well. I'm hoping to get this working through the controller.

Here is my form with the ActiveCourse.CourseName and Credits added as hidden values:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<form class="row" asp-controller="Course"
        asp-action="AddBookToCourseById" asp-route-id="@Model.ActiveCourse.CourseId"
        method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="visually-hidden" asp-for="NewBook.Title">Title</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-text">Title</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="NewBook.Title" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="visually-hidden" asp-for="NewBook.Author">Author</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-text">Author</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="NewBook.Author" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="visually-hidden" asp-for="NewBook.YearPublished">Year</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-text">Year</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="NewBook.YearPublished" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Seems to only work when adding hidden info for activecourse name and credits -->
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ActiveCourse.CourseName" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ActiveCourse.Credits" />

    <!-- Add th Id (i.e. PK) field as a hidden input element: -->
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ActiveCourse.CourseId" />

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Book</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Please post CourseDetailsViewModel code as well.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that, just added it. Should I add the entities as well? I wanted to add more but was worried that maybe I would be adding too much

Comment: What's the type of ActiveCourse, which I presume it's your binded model?

Comment: ActiveCourse is the type "Course". I use it to check track of the course being used in the page.

Comment: Hi @RedGecko, what is the version of asp.net core? Besides, what is your `courseDetailsViewModel` value you receive and what is the new `courseDetailsViewModel` value after modelstate is not valid? It works fine in my side without any error here. If possible, maybe share a minimal repo which can reproduce your issue would be better.